# How to count how many times a character appears in a row

Tags: ruby

My code works well with regular character count

```
count = Hash.new(0)
str.each_char do |char|
    count[char] += 1 unless char == " "
end
count
```

For example, `"aaabbaaaaacccbbdddd"` would equal to 'a' = 8, 'b' = 4, 'c' = 3, 'd' = 4.

I want to do how many times it occurs in a row. The results I want are:
'a' = 3, 'b' = 2, 'a' = 5 'c' = 3, 'b' = 2, and 'd' = 4. How can I do this?

Comment: You could not get this result, because each key in `hash` must be different

Comment: What is ecpected output for `abab`?

Comment: @WandMaker `a = 1, b = 1, a = 1, b = 1`

Comment: It would be more clear if, in your title, you replaced "row" with "string". Most will read "in a row" as consecutive, as Ruby has no concept of "rows". (I suggest you edit.)

Answer (score 7):

```
"aaabbaaaaacccbbdddd".each_char.chunk(&:itself).map{|k, v| [k, v.length]}
# => [["a", 3], ["b", 2], ["a", 5], ["c", 3], ["b", 2], ["d", 4]]
```

---

I benchmarked the solutions from sawa and spickermann:

```
require 'benchmark/ips'

def sawa(string)
  string.each_char.chunk(&:itself).map{|k, v| [k, v.length] }
end

def spickermann(string)
  string.split(//).slice_when { |a, b| a != b }.map { |group| [group.first, group.size] }
end

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  string = "aaabbaaaaacccbbdddd"

  x.report("sawa") { sawa string }
  x.report("spickerman") { spickermann string }

  x.compare!
end

# Calculating -------------------------------------
#                 sawa     6.293k i/100ms
#          spickermann     4.447k i/100ms
# -------------------------------------------------
#                 sawa     75.353k (±10.4%) i/s -    371.287k
#          spickermann     48.661k (±12.0%) i/s -    240.138k
# 
# Comparison:
#                 sawa:    75353.5 i/s
#          spickermann:    48660.7 i/s - 1.55x slower
```

Comment: This answer would be even better if it explained `chunk(&:itself)`.

Comment: @Schwern, I am of two minds about explaining `chunk(&:itself)`. Nowadays I seem to see it here on SO so often (several times today) that I wonder how many benefit from an explanation. Like [Array#to_h](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h) it may have reached the point where it needn't be explained if no one asks.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Make it simple and consider the OP foremost, the answers are primarily for them. Based on the relative simplicity of the question I doubt they've seen chunk. I hadn't. chunk is also a bit more involved to explain than Array#to_h as evidenced by my explanation in my answer. You could even write a blog post to link to in the future.

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```
string.split(//).slice_when { |a, b| a != b }.
       map { |group| [group.first, group.size] }

#=> [['a', 3], ['b', 2], ['a', 5], ['c', 3], ['b', 2], ['d', 4]]
```

Comment: As @sawa is fond of saying, it's "sad" you didn't use [Enumerable#chunk_while](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while),  as its block (`{ |a,b| a==b }`) does not contain a negation. `chunk_while` was new in v2.3, [Enumerable#slice_when](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when) in v2.2. I feel like a broken record recommending [String#each_char](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-each_char) over `split //` or `chars` when chaining to an enumerable instance method, to avoid the creation of a temporary array.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a hash, use an array to store pairs as you see them.

```
str = "aaabbaaaaacccbbdddd"

counts = []
str.each_char do |char|
  # Get the last seen character and count pair
  last_pair = counts[-1] || []

  if last_pair[0] == char
    # This character is the same as the last one, increment its count
    last_pair[1] += 1
  else
    # New character, push a new pair onto the list
    counts.push([char, 1])
  end

end

counts.each { |c|
  puts "#{c[0]} = #{c[1]}"
}
```

This can be written much more concisely using [chunk](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk).

```
str = "aaabbaaaaacccbbdddd"
counts = []
str.chars.chunk(&:itself).each { |char, chars|
  counts << [char, chars.length]
}
puts counts.inspect
```

`chunk` splits a list into chunks. It decides this by calling the block on each element. As long as the block returns the same value as the previous value, it will add to the current chunk. Once it changes, it makes a new chunk. This is similar to what we were doing in the loop before by storing the last seen character.

```
  if last_seen == char
    # it's the same chunk
  else
    # it's a new chunk
    last_seen = char
  end
```

[`itself`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-itself) returns the character right back.  So `chunk(&:itself)` will split the string into chunks of characters.

The new list is the return value of `chunk(&:itself)` (in our case the character in this chunk) plus the actual chunk (for example the string "aaa").

Comment: To be more accurate, `chunk` does not call a method on each element. It calls a block on each element. It is the `&` with `Symbol#to_proc` that changes the symbol to a proc to a block. I can't interpret the "into a function" part in that sentence.

Comment: @sawa Yeah, I rewrote that a few times and don't seem to have finished. I'm on a phone, please feel free to edit.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer regular expressions for this kind of problems:

```
str = "aaabbaaaaacccbbdddd"
counts = str.scan(/(?<seq>(?<char>\w)\k<char>+)/).inject([]) do |occurs, match|
  occurs << [match[1], match[0].size]

  occurs
end
puts counts.inspect #=>[["a", 3], ["b", 2], ["a", 5], ["c", 3], ["b", 2], ["d", 4]]
```

**Edit:**

I ran the same benchmark with @sawa and I added the regular expression way. It seems a little faster. Furthermore, `#itself` is not working for `ruby < 2.2.x`

```
require 'benchmark/ips'

def sawa(string)
  string.each_char.chunk(&:itself).map{|k, v| [k, v.length] }
end

def spickermann(string)
  string.split(//).slice_when { |a, b| a != b }.map { |group| [group.first, group.size] }
end

def stathopa(string)
  string.scan(/(?<seq>(?<char>\w)\k<char>+)/).inject([]) do |occurs, match|
    occurs << [match[1], match[0].size]

    occurs
  end
end

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  string = "aaabbaaaaacccbbdddd"

  x.report("sawa") { sawa string }
  x.report("spickerman") { spickermann string }
  x.report("stathopa") { stathopa string }

  x.compare!
end

# Calculating -------------------------------------
#                 sawa     6.730k i/100ms
#           spickerman     4.061k i/100ms
#             stathopa    11.969k i/100ms
# -------------------------------------------------
#                 sawa     70.072k (± 8.9%) i/s -    349.960k
#           spickerman     43.652k (± 9.5%) i/s -    219.294k
#             stathopa    132.992k (± 8.8%) i/s -    670.264k
# 
# Comparison:
#             stathopa:   132992.1 i/s
#                 sawa:    70072.4 i/s - 1.90x slower
#           spickerman:    43651.6 i/s - 3.05x slower
#
```

Answer (score 0):

To count the maximum length sequence of each character:

```
count = Hash.new(0)
last_char = nil
occurred = 0
str.each_char do |char|
    if char != last_char
      occurred = 1
    else
      occurred += 1
    end
    last_char = char
    count[char] = occurred if (count[char]||0) < occurred
end
count
```

Or to get the result like [['a',3],['b',2],['a',5],['c',3],['b',2],['d',4]]:

```
count = []
last_char = nil
occurred = 0
str.each_char do |char|
    if char != last_char
      count.push([last_char, occurred])
      occurred = 1
    else
      occurred += 1
    end
    last_char = char
end
count.push([last_char, occurred])
count
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this:

```
s = "aaabbaaaaacccbbdddd"
s.chars.uniq.map do |c|
  p [c, s.split(/[^#{c}]+/).reject(&:empty?).map(&:size)]
end.to_h
#=> {"a"=>[3, 5], "b"=>[2, 2], "c"=>[3], "d"=>[4]}
```