# Finding the length of repeating elements in an array

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I would like to find the length of streaks within the following array:

```
states = [:read, :read, :read, :unread, :unread, :read, :read, :read, :read]
```

The array has either `:read` or `:unread`, and I want the length of each streak of `:read`/`:unread`. For `states`, this would become:

```
streak_lengths = [3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

The array opens with three `:read` elements, and we label each of those as being part of a `3` streak, it then has two `:unread` elements, so they're each labelled with a `2` streak, and then finally we have a  streak of four read messages, so they're each labelled with a `4`.

What is an elegant, efficient and readable way to solve the above problem?

Is it a recursion problem? While I can solve this problem, I feel that it hints at a way of tackling it that I'm not familiar with. It hints that perhaps it's something best solved with recursion.

(For the benefit of the "possibly duplicate" flag applied to this: both threads actually have slightly different discussions. In addition from a search perspective, you would only find the other thread if you search for repeating characters, this the answer to how you detect repeating array elements. Finally there are a load of excellent answers on here, removing this question wouldn't make the ecosystem richer, just poorer)

Comment: so if the input is [:read, :read, :unread, :unread], then you would get [2,2,2,2]?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking, we expect to see an example of your effort, either what you tried and an explanation of why it didn't work, or where you've searched and why those places didn't help. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Showing us your effort helps as a lot of people won't try to help you if you haven't shown you tried to help yourself first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count how many times a character appears in a row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246308/how-to-count-how-many-times-a-character-appears-in-a-row)  (and i find it strange that this fairly uncommon question gets asked twice in a row almost at the same time and both have the mostly the same answers including the same comment discussions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`chunk` segments into an array consecutive elements that have identical return value when the block is called on them. `flat_map` concats the arrays returned by the block into a single one.

```
states.chunk(&:itself).flat_map{|_, a| Array.new(a.length, a.length)}
# => [3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Perhaps you can do it in a recursive way if you want, but I don't think that would lead to an elegant solution. From my experience, it is better to avoid recursion whenever possible.

Comment: please explain it

Comment: .chunk looks like the right solution but could you elaborate on your answer @sawa, it's powerful but I'd love to know what your logic is so that I can expand it to being more readable in my code. Also in Ruby 2.1.8 it doesn't unfortunately work: `NoMethodError: undefined method `itself' for :read:Symbol`

Comment: @sawa nice solution. Add an explanation, and I'll upvote.

Comment: @PeterNixey `itself` was introduced with Ruby 2.2. You could write `chunk { |e| e }` instead.

Comment: An answer with an explanation! Nice work, @sawa. (Upvoted, natch.)

Answer (score 5):

With Ruby v2.2

```
states.slice_when { |a,b| a != b }.flat_map { |a| [a.size]*a.size }
  #=> [3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

With Ruby v2.3

```
states.chunk_while { |a,b| a == b }.flat_map { |a| [a.size]*a.size }
  #=> [3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

but neither of these offer any advantage over plain old `chunk`.

Comment: I am still sad that you are using `slice_when` instead of `chunk_while`.

Comment: @sawa, remembering "sad", I added `chunk_while` before seeing your comment.

Comment: Nice. IMO `slice_when` is more concise than `chunk(&:itself)`.

Comment: @sschmeck Its block is more complicated.

Comment: ...and my `slice_when` is 11 characters longer. I would have used `chunk(&:itself)` had it not been taken.

Answer (score 2):

This is practically what the most simple compression algorithms do and in that context it is called Run-Length Encoding or RLE in short.

There's a couple of Ruby examples of how to implement RLE in Ruby found on [RosettaCode's Wiki Page on RLE](http://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding#Ruby)

The most relevant example concerning your question is probably the first one:

```
# run_encode("aaabbbbc") #=> [["a", 3], ["b", 4], ["c", 1]]
def run_encode(string)
  string
    .chars
    .chunk{|i| i}
    .map {|kind, array| [kind, array.length]}
end
```

This uses the [chunk](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) method found in Ruby's own Enumerator class that is common for classes you can enumerate on, such as Arrays and Hashes. It *Enumerates over the items, chunking them together based on the return value of the block.*

Learning from the example, we can get the kind of output you asked for with the following code (flat_map usage borrowed from @sawa 's answer since mine didn't actually return [2, 2] from [:read, :read] but only [2](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk)):

```
states = [:read, :read, :read, :unread, :unread, :read, :read, :read, :read]
states.chunk{|a| a}.flat_map{|_, a| [a.length] * a.length}
# outputs [3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Comment: What is the point of repeating my answer in two different guises?

Comment: @sawa : I wrote mine earlier and edited it as I noticed my output wasn't as expected.

Comment: A small point: when `chars` is chained to an `Enumerable` instance method, it's preferable to use `each_char`, which returns and enumerable and thereby avoids the creation of a temporary array.

Answer (score 0):

All nice answers are already posted, hence, I am posting another way to do this - it takes the advantage of the fact if array elements are references to another existing array, then, modification to that existing array will be visible to all elements that reference it.

For example:

```
a = [1]
b = [a, a, a, a]
#=> [[1], [1], [1], [1]]
a[0] = 2
b
#=> [[2], [2], [2], [2]]
```

---

```
states = [:read, :read, :read, :unread, :unread, :read, :read, :read, :read]

t = [1]
result = []
states.each_with_index do |ele, i|
  result[i] = t
  if i + 1 < states.size and states[i+1] == states[i]
    result[i][0] += 1
  else
    t = [1] 
  end
end

p result.flatten
#=> [3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```